How can I combine end select elements into -ocustom-columns?

How to use -ocustom-colums to achieve the same effect as in the PORT(s) column of the kubectl get service command (i.e. using / to concatenate the values ​​of the .spec.ports.port and .spec.ports.protocol pairs)

# kubectl get service web
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
web          ClusterIP   10.222.0.1   <none>        443/TCP   57d

# kubectl get service web -oyaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.222.0.1
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.222.0.1
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}



And how to add a condition similar to what subject.name specifies in the USERS column if .subject.kind==User

# kubectl get rolebindings viewer -owide
NAME     ROLE               AGE   USERS       GROUPS       SERVICEACCOUNTS
viewer   ClusterRole/view   54s   view-user   view-group

# kubectl get rolebindings viewer -oyaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: viewer
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: view-user
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Group
  name: view-group

directives of the type  'PORTs:.spec.ports.port'/'.spec.ports.protocol'  don't work
